# How to use arcpy module in Anaconda's install of Spyder?

Tags: python, arcgis, anaconda, spyder, arcpy

I recently installed Anaconda's Python distribution, which includes Spyder IDE.  I am interested in importing the ArcGIS 10.3 `arcpy` module in Spyder.  Unfortunately, running `import arcpy` results in the following error:

```
import arcpy
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-50d283eebbb3>", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting

ImportError: No module named arcgisscripting
```

To resolve this error, I have tried 1) changing the interpreter to `ArcMap.exe` and 2) moving the `Desktop10.1.pth` file, both as shown in [this SE post](http://quia.cf/orange/pooxy4/nph-poxy.pl/es/20/http/stackoverflow.com/questions/19795469/importing-arcpy-module-into-anacondas-spyder).  Solution #1 crashes Spyder and solution #2 has no effect.

What steps are needed to be able to import and use the `arcpy` module in the Anaconda distribution of Spyder?

Answer (score 1):

A good explanation on how to do this [here](https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/locating-python-adding-to-path-and-accessing-arcpy/)

> To allow other Python installations to access Arcpy a file must be copied from the \Lib\site-packages\ folder within the Arc Python installation and placed in the corresponding folder of the non-Arc Python. If you have not installed 64-bit background geoprocessing the file is Desktop10.1.pth; if you have installed it, the file is DTBGGP64.pth.

I strongly recommend reading that post.