# import arcpy--ImportError ：cannot import name 'gp' from 'arcpy.geoprocessing'

Tags: python, anaconda, arcpy

I am confronted with the problem that the title said, when I "import arcpy" using python (in Anaconda`s environment) for working.

```py
>>>import arcpy

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-5467a3dc9fe3>", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy

  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp

ImportError: cannot import name 'gp' from 'arcpy.geoprocessing' (D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py)
```

In fact, I already have met an "import arcpy" problem, and I've added "D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy" and "D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy" into the environment variable "PYTHONPATH" .Then the problem described in the title came to me.

I have tried a variety of methods, also done as the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789526/how-to-use-arcpy-module-in-anacondas-install-of-spyder), but still can not solve the problem! Do I have to reinstall Anaconda or one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start by purging and reinstalling arcpy. Be sure you're using the right installer if you have more than one version of Python installed (I.e. you may have a `pip` for python2.7 and `pip3` for python 3.x).

```
pip uninstall arcgis #(or)
pip3 uninstall arcgis #(or)
pip uninstall --user arcgis #(if it was installed to the local user only)

pip(3) (--user) install arcgis
```

The fact that it's finding `line 21` in `D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py` makes my think the package is installed, and you are pointed to the site-packages (albeit - is it the RIGHT site-packages) BUT it can't find `gp` within it's files.

Also, if you DO have more than one Python installed, make sure the `site-packages` to which you're pointing matches the python version that is running.

I am curious as to why `site-packages` (or `dist-packages`) does not appear in the path. Are you sure this is the path to the actual full package?

Comment: In fact, when I install the ArcGis 10.2, the python 2.7.3 was installed along. Then I use the `import arcpy` in the Anaconda's environment. It was mentioned that i have added the `site-packages` or others in the path. I tried ```pip3 install arcpy```, but it prompts the errors.

Comment: `C:\Users\XXXXX>pip3 install arcpy
Collecting arcpy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement arcpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for arcpy`

Comment: Sorry. `pip3 install arcgis`

Comment: Thank you very much!But it still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: This package "arcpy" is something of god. Isn't it compatible with py3? Oops!! I'm falling apart!

Comment: yes！In fact, I'm actually a beginner, just use this "arcpy" package.I tried to build my environment in py2 and it worked! But py2 has stopped updating. I've never used py2, which need to reinstall many packages again!  I just want to "import arcpy" in Anaconda environment (Spyder or Juypter). Thank you!